# WiFi icon often not appearing in icons tray

Tags: networking, kubuntu, icons, system-tray

I installed Kubuntu 15.10 since a couple of days on my computer.

I noticed that the WiFi icon does not appear in the icon tray at startup, and this makes managing the network connection quite longer. At its place there is just a white spot I can't click on.

Yesterday the icon appeared after a while I was working on the computer, while using Kubuntu from Live USB I noticed that sometimes, already at startup, the icon was there (usually I had to select the english language to have it appear).

This is the situation at the moment.

[image]

Of course I'd like the situation to be normal, and the wifi icon to be always there. How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you edit `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the little triangle in the tray and choose System Tray Settings. On the Display page, ensure that all categories are selected, and that the Network Management extra item is selected. On the Entries page page, ensure that visibility for Network Management is set to Auto.